# how to use scrollview in layout with toolbar and bottomnavigationview?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have a screen in which there is a **toolbar**, a **bottomNavigationView** and some data between them including a **textView** and an **imageView**. I want to scroll the inner data that is between the *toolbar and bottomNavigationView.*

I want to scroll the design.xml inside of main.xml. Please suggest a way I can achieve this.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<include
    layout="@layout/design"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</ScrollView>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="#FFFFFF"
    app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

**design.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    tools:context="com.example.chaitanya.pg.Pgdata">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relative">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btt1"
            android:background="@drawable/tprevoius"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/tnext"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btt1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/btt2" />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/cardview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/viewPager"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
            card_view:cardMaxElevation="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Facilities"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:id="@+id/facilities"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/wifi"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/ac"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:foregroundGravity="right"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/food"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/cardview12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/cardview1"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
            card_view:cardMaxElevation="5dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Accomodation"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/accomodation"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/cardview123"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/cardview12"
            android:layout_margin="6dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFF"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
            card_view:cardMaxElevation="5dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Price"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/pricee"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
         android:id="@+id/name"
         android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
         android:textStyle="italic"
         android:textSize="20dp"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
         android:paddingLeft="20dp"

         />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/name"
            android:id="@+id/addr"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"

           />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Whats the problem that you are facing? The elements are overlapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There needs to be only one layout inside `ScrollView`.
2. You do not need to put `ScrollView` inside `ScrollView`.
   You have added the include tag inside the `ScrollView` and your
   design.xml also has `ScrollView`.
3. I would not use android:fillViewport tag inside ScrollView, instead
   use properties related to relative layout.

Rest of the things don't seem too difficult to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

from `design.xml` remove parent `<ScrollView>` because outsie you already define the scrollview so there is no use of scrollview inside the `design.xml`

**design.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```